# How can I make a program so that it runs on all window versions?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I use spyder(ide) for writing python programs.

I wrote a program on 'conway checkers' using tkinter(gui library).

I then compiled this program using pyinstaller into a '.exe' file. However, this '.exe' file does not run on any other computer except mine.

What else is required to make it run on all windows just like any other application does?

Comment: *does not run* is a tad bit too vague. What errors/messages does windows give you on 'any other computer' ? What version of Windows have you used to 'compile' this and what versions have you tried running the .exe on ?

Comment: Pyinstaller appears to allow for both - a single .exe as well as multiple files in a directory. Since your 'single exe' isnt working out, try the other ?

Comment: Depending on the error message, you might want to add the dependencies (dll?) with shipping the exe to another computer in the same folder. But without an error message, this is a guess

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make it easy for others to help you effectively by including all relevant details from the start. – Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ive made a gui using `tkinter` and many other modules(`pygame`,`os`,`numpy`) and sent it to many people across the globe, and it has worked for all of them. Maybe there is some other error, you might want to run `pyinstaller -c -F appname.py` and see what error comes up on the console on the diff machine and then configure based on that. My best guess for the error is that the system path and the project files, like images are not in the path as it is said in your code. Do let me know :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

However, your problem is probably related to missing libraries on other people's computers.
You can either:

- Use a "requirements.txt" file, in which you specify what libraries is needed to run your program (tkinter in your case it would seem) and explain how to install it using pip in a Readme
- Export an environment and pack it in the .exe file

To troubleshoot your issue, run your exe file in a windows command prompt, you will get hints of what your issue is.